# Terminal and other services do not work

Tags: linux-mint, python, gnome-terminal

I am using Linux Mint, and since today,  there is a strange bug. Several services won't work, such as terminal or update manager. Backup Service asks for the root password, but then does not launch either. Other such as System Parameters or Synaptic work fine.

I manage to access a terminal by installing another one, so I can type commands. Shortcuts to terminal such as ctrl+alt+T or ctrl+alt+F1 (to F7) do not work either.

Also redshift is supposed to launch at startup, which it does not do anymore.

Presumably the problem was caused by trying to install different versions of python3 and pip3, in order to install a program called katrain, which I did not succeed to do. Here is the error when trying to install, I copy it in case it is linked with the system-wide bug:

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-5da9i7i5/pyobjus/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-5da9i7i5/pyobjus/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-q_pdphzf
     cwd: /tmp/pip-install-5da9i7i5/pyobjus/
Complete output (5 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-install-5da9i7i5/pyobjus/setup.py", line 58, in <module>
    cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext},
NameError: name 'build_ext' is not defined
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py 
egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

How can I put the system back to normal ? (Or where to look for help if here is not appropriate)

Some info about the system:

- Mint 18 Cinnamon 64-bit, version 3.0.7
- Kernel 4.4.0-120-generic

Comment: Found the answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/880188/gnome-terminal-will-not-start